Vite - Building efficiently different applications based on common source code
I am currently developing a web application with Vue.js and Vite.
I aim to produce two different versions of the same application using the same source code. For example, some components are common between the two versions, while others are specific to a particular version, including images.
We could build two separate applications using different repositories; however, there are many similarities between the two apps (components, deployment, Dockerfile, CSS, etc.). Therefore, I believe that the most efficient way to maintain them is to consolidate everything into a single source code repository.
At present, I have an environment variable VITE_VERSION that specifies which version should be displayed to the end user using if/else statements. However, this approach raises several issues:

The bundled files (e.g., the public folder) are common for all versions, exposing pictures, logos, views, etc., if someone knows where to look.

Code maintenance is not optimized; throughout my codebase, I have several 'versionA', 'versionB', and 'master' folders to logically separate my files.
|
├── dist                                    
│   └── [...]                  
|  
├── node_modules                            
│   └── [...]   
|              
├── public
│   ├── versionA    
|   |   |── favicon.ico                         
|   |   |── web.config                          
|   |   |── robot.txt                           
|   |   └── img                                 
|   |       └── [...]
|   |                            
│   └── versionB
|       |── favicon.ico                         
|       |── web.config                          
|       |── robot.txt                           
|       └── img                                 
|           └── [...]
|
├── src                                  
│   |── assets                              
|   |   ├── versionA                        
|   |   |   └── [...] 
|   |   |
|   |   └── versionB
|   |       └── [...]
|   |
|   |
│   |── components                          
|   |   ├── versionA                        
|   |   |   └── [...] 
|   |   |
|   |   └── versionB
|   |       └── [...]
...       



However, this file organization becomes increasingly complex and error-prone as more versions are added. Therefore, I am seeking a more elegant and secure solution, such as:

Building master files and version-specific files based on a given parameter (e.g., vite build --version A).

Organizing my code structure to include only 'versionA', 'versionB', and 'master' folders, along with common project configuration files (e.g., .env.production, tsconfig.json).
|
├── dist                                    
│   └── [...]                  
|  
├── node_modules                            
│   └── [...]   
|              
├── versionA          # Specific code for version A
│   ├── public    
|   |   └── [...]
|   |                            
│   └── src
|       └── [...]
├── versionB          # Specific code for version B
│   ├── public    
|   |   └── [...]
|   |                            
│   └── src
|       └── [...]
├── master            # Shared code between versions
│   ├── public    
|   |   └── [...]
|   |                            
│   └── src
|       └── [...]
...  



Is it possible to achieve these goals using Vue.js and Vite?

You can use a monorepo. This makes it easier to import files between subprojects. This is something that you try to achieve with the last structure
